# KeycloakConfigResolver (Multi Tenant) is called many times

Tags: keycloak, multi-tenant

I am implementing my custom Keycloak config resolver in that way to find a solution for multitenant propose.
I have a keyclock-multitenant.properties where i have a definition of my realms (array).

```
public class MyKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver

 @Override
 public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {
        System.out.println("resolve");
        ...
    }
```

and inside of the above override method (resolve) i do some call's to private methods (get token, issuer claim, etc).

It's working and i can match the realm Keycloak config according to the issue of the token. But my little problem is when i do a simple GET request (for exemple) the print in method is written thirteen times in one request (private methods as well) and performance well becomes more degraded.

What could be causing the loop?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that the actual KeycloakDeployment returned by the resolve-method is typically cached, then it would be a cheap operation and no real problem if it is called multiple times. But I guess the only way to get a definite answer in your case it to pull out a debugger.

Comment: ok ... so it might be perfectly normal to have this repetition in the method resolve to be called more than once in a request ?

Comment: It looks like it. It might for instance be multiple steps in the same filter chain that needs the information. 13 times sound perhaps a bit much, but still not a dramatic amount.